# How do I delete a created tag?

Tags: support

I accidentally created a tag called [full] when I was asking a FMA question and I accidentally pressed enter and created the tag [full]. How do I delete it? I am panicking cause people may think I am doing this on purpose.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the tag from whatever questions it's currently on (at the moment there are none so you're already done with that). After that, just wait for the tag to be automatically removed. This should happen daily at 3:00 UTC so long as it isn't being used on any questions at that time.

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure to be more careful next time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tags not used in any question are automagically deleted by the system in 24 hours. Just remove the tag from whatever question it has it and try to keep it like that ;)